# How to get google sign in access token in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to get the access token from google sign in. I already did google login coding but I only get displayName, email, id, photoUrl. Can I know how to get the access token?

Here is my code:

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
  GoogleSignInAccount _currentUser;
  String _contactText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
    });
  }


  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      var user = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      print(user);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignOut() => _googleSignIn.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GoogleSignInAuthentication` class to get access token;

```
Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
  try {
    GoogleSignInAccount user = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await user.authentication;

    print(googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);


  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but my google sign in is without using firebase.

Comment: You're welcome, I edited the code. You can try now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
_googleSignIn.signIn().then((result){
          result.authentication.then((googleKey){
              print(googleKey.accessToken);
              print(googleKey.idToken);
          }).catchError((err){
            print('Error occured inside');
          });
      }).catchError((err){
          print('Error occured outside');
      });
```

Enjoy coding!